# Is it possible to hook up a anonymous Delegate using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

From this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976.aspx), there's quite a few ways to hook up a delegate using reflection.

It seems the best way is with the CreateDelegate method:

```
Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, targetObject, handlerMethodName);
```

Under normal circumstances, I'd be pointing to the handler method that is within the targetObject class.
But what if the delegate was created anonymously?  Example:

```
public delegate void SelectedVehiclesCollectionDelegate(string query, List<Vehicles> list);
...
myObject.SelectedVehiclesCollection = (query, list) =>
                    {
                      //assign list of vehicles to list matching query
                    };
```

There's not a method within the class definition to which the delegate is referencing. I need to invoke this delegate which is unknown at runtime, obtaining the list of items are a result.

Ok, looks like my terminology got the best of me.  Wasnt aiming at creating a handler but invoke what's already there (Tomas Petricek's answer still gives me some good insight though).

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You use `CreateDelegate` when you don't already have a delegate. If you have an anonymous delegate then you obviously already have a delegate. So what are you asking?

Comment: Ah, that may be my problem.  To clarify: the delegate of myObject.SelectedVehiclesCollection is assigned and ready. My class has a property of Type SelectedVehiclesCollectionDelegate.
 
So, using Reflection, I can 'navigate' to the correct property. My need is to call that delegate with parameters.

I think I approached this from the wrong direction; possibly need to use PropertyInfo.GetValue().  I'll examine closely and post when closer to a solution.

Comment: The article you link to (and the term "to hook up") both refer to adding a delegate as an event handler. It sounds like you want to invoke the delegate (using its `.Invoke()` or `.DynamicInvoke()` method, which can be done regardless of how you create it), not hook it up to an event.

Comment: I just realized something: while Jon Skeet's answer gave me a solution to my problem, Tomas Petricek's answer is actually more applicable to the *specific* question asked (my confusion over the MSDN article's approach nonwithstanding).
So in the spirit of the question (and not my misunderstanding), what (in the community's opinion) would be the 'correct' answer? I'm thinking in terms of someone finding this question and missing Tomas' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your comment, it sounds like this is about *calling* a delegate rather than *creating* one, in which case [`Delegate.DynamicInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx) is probably what you're after, if you really don't know the relevant delegate type at compile time.

If you *do* know the relevant delegate type, just not the property name, you can cast:

```
MyDelegate handler = (MyDelegate) propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
handler(...); // Call as normal
```

Comment: I think you have me there.  The approach i was trying looks more used in attaching to an event etc.

Answer (score 1):

Under the cover, the anonymous delegate is compiled into a class, so there is still some target object and method name. The class can contain some additional fields as well - if you capture a local variable inside the method, it becomes a member of the class.

If you want to have a simple way to create anonymous delegates and hook them up using Reflection, you can write a very simple class:

```
class Closure {
  public Action Operation { get; set; }
  public void Invoke() { Operation(); }
}
```

Then you can create an operation using something like this (and use `Invoke` as the target method):

```
var op = new Closure { Operation = delegate() { .. } };
```

It depends on what exactly are you trying to do - the point of hooking events using Reflection is that you just have some method that you want to run. If you have a delegate (e.g. `Action`) then you can use it directly. A class like this may be useful if you want to create a delegate unknown at compile time.

Comment: It sounds like the OP is confused and merely wants to invoke delegates, not hook them up to events.